# How to get the count of field of last 1 week ,last 1 month ,yesterday

Tags: mysql, datediff

I want to get count of customers **city wise** of today ,yesterday ,last week ,last month .

I want Result like

```
    city today yesterday lastweek lastmnth
     1     23     2         12         12
```

I have my table structure like the following

customers

```
    c_id  city_id  c_name            currentdate
     1      1       Rama             2015-01-30 09:43:17
     2      1       kavitha          2015-04-30 09:43:17
```

cities

```
    city_id   city_name
     1          hyd
     2          Wgl
```

I tried it with following .

```
 select c.c_city, (select count(cr_id)  as lastmonth  from customer 
  where currentdate > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) )) from customers as c
  left join cities as ci on c.city_id = ci.city_id group by c.city_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to this:

```
SELECT city_id as city,
SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(currentdate,10) = LEFT(NOW(),10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as today,
SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(currentdate,10) = LEFT(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY,10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as yesterday,
SUM(CASE WHEN currentdate > NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as lastweek,
SUM(CASE WHEN currentdate > NOW()-INTERVAL 30 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as lastmnth
FROM customers GROUP BY city_id
```

For last week and last month, I'm assuming you mean 7 days back and 30 days back. If you however need data from previous week and from previous month (which doesn't make much sense to me in this context) you may need to rewrite the intervals.